# how i can Locate the element with id in python , visible?

Tags: python-3.x

i need a way to Locate the element with id in project of filling form . i am using http send request for form filling so i cant use selenium.

example javascript code is :

```
document.getElementById("id name").innerHTML="answer";
```

Comment: which error you get?  whats your problem here? the syntax seems ok

Comment: i solved it. thanks